# Why is Odyssey "odyssey" but Iliad isn't "iliad"?

Tags: etymology

Why did "odyssey" come to commonly mean "journey" while Iliad didn't come to have any common meaning?

Comment: That's the way things work in language change. Every word has its own unique life history, and lives and dies individually, just like people.

Comment: https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/002/028/956/037.jpg explains odyssey.

Comment: How did *journey*, literally a day (and thence a day-trip), come to apply to something that took twenty years?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *Iliad* does mean, in English,

> A long series of disasters or the like (Greek ἰλιάς κακῶν, Demosthenes); a long story or account.

(*Oxford English Dictionary* (OED)), so the usage is the same as that of *the Odyssey*. It is not as common.

Two examples are

> 1609   Bp. W. Barlow Answer Catholike English-man 359   Her stay brought forth..an Iliad of miseries.

and

> 1865   Times 29 Apr.   An opportunity of learning a whole Iliad of finance in a comparative nutshell.

Comment: It's rare enough to have kept the capital *I* by the look of things, while *odyssey* is often used with a lowercase *O*.

Comment: Those could both be metaphors, in fact.

Answer (score 0):

John Lawler above is correct. Words become popular on their own, because people decide to use them. Odyssey is a word that means a great journey, because *The Odyssey* by Homer tells the tale of a great journey. Everyone has had some personal kind of odyssey in their life, even if they haven't travelled far. People have odysseys by way of personal growth or overcoming a series of difficulties. In the end, *The Odyssey* by Homer ends happily, with Odysseus finally returning home, while in *The Iliad*, the war is won, but it's basically a tragic story. So it makes sense that people would use a word more when it refers to a happy or fulfilling ending.

Comment: One does not capitalize the word "the" when writing "the *Iliad*" and "the *Odyssey*". And the name of the work should be set in italic.

Comment: Actually, no, tchrist. The Odyssey is the name of the epic poem. It says on the title, The Odyssey, Homer. Same with The Iliad. So the correct way to write it is with a capital T -The. you're right about italics, didn't know how to do them here but I see it now.

Comment: I own the renowned Robert Fagles translations of both works. He absolutely never capitalizes the word “the” nor sets it in italic when referring to either work, and he invariably does both these things with the work itself. On page 21 of the *Iliad* Fagles writes: “Archaeological evidence for Phoenician imports into Greece dates from the ninth century ʙ.ᴄ. and Phoenician traders are mentioned in the *Iliad* (23.828) and their operations described with a wealth of detail in the *Odyssey*.” I consider Fagles an **authoritative reference** on these works and their treatment, and you should, too.

Comment: I also have Fagel's translation, and Fitzgerald's, and Lombardo's, and it's true that in the introductions they don't capitalize or italicize 'The' when writing 'the Odyssey.' But, it's a subtle point, they are referring to the work in the way a lot of writers refer to works. For example, some will write "Kafka's Metamorphosis is..." without including its actual title, "The Metamorphosis." I also have Emily Wilson's recent translation of "The Odyssey," and throughout the introduction, she uses italics and capitalizes - as "The Odyssey." It appears to be a negotiable point, then, I would say.

Comment: I don't know how to italicize in these comments boxes, sorry.